# Are all data types a specific type of an Object?

Tags: java, php, javascript, programming-languages

> Are all data types a specific type of an Object?

If I call Array a type of Object, then what would I call the values inside the Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the programming language. For example there exist no objects in **C**. Here, an array is a continuous space in memory.

In **PHP**, arrays are not objects either, but they are implemented as hash maps.

<del>In **Java**, arrays are not objects, but they can contain objects. On the other side, `ArrayList`s are objects and can only contain objects.</del> *Edit: See comment.*

In **JavaScript**, everything but the primitive types are objects, also arrays.

---

You have to be careful to distinguish between the terminology of the language and the general data structure.

Comment: In Java, arrays are objects. Both `new Object[0] instanceof Object` and `new int[0] instanceof Object` return `true`. But, in general, you are correct.

Comment: @CajunLuke: Uh ok. That shows my lack of Java knowledge... Thanks!

Comment: @Felix It's cool. The knowledge that arrays are objects in Java is rarely useful. One never uses one as an object directly; that's why we have ArrayList.

Comment: "One never uses one as an object directly" Can you brief it pls

Comment: @radkrish: In order for @Cajun to be notified about your comment, you have to mention him with an @, like I did.

Comment: @radkrish: @Cajun probably means that you don't do most things on an array that you would do on a single object, like calling class methods.